# SQL Query to generate al the fiscal years going forward

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I need to write SQL query that will give me all the fiscal years going forward 10/01/2015. So for now it should return 2016, after 10/01/2016, the query should return 2016, 2017. Same as after 10/01/2017, the query should return 2016,2017, 2018. I am having tough time coming up with any logic for this Query.I need to put the query as a parameter for SSRS report.
 Any help is appreciated. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a list, specifying a start and end using a recursive query like this:

```
with cte(YR) 
as(select cast('10/1/2016' as date) as YR
   union all
   Select dateadd(year, 1, YR)
   from cte
   where YR < cast('10/1/2020' as date)
)    

select * from cte;
```

Comment: Thank you Mo2. I am playing with this general logic to try to make it work for me. I will let you know what I might end up using. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I came up with based on Mo's Suggestion.

```
declare @curMonth int
set @curMonth = datepart(month, getdate()); 

with cte(YR)
as(select cast('10/1/2016' as date) as YR
   union all
   Select dateadd(year, 1, YR)
   from cte
   where YR < case 
        when @curmonth >= 10
        then dateadd(year, 1, getdate())
        else cast(getdate() as date)
        end
)    

select datepart(year,YR) as YR from cte;
```

Thank you Mo2 and John Cappeliti for your answers.